# How hard would it be to scramble crypto keys in memory on command?

Tags: linux, key-management, memory

I'm looking for a way locate a set of keys in memory on command.

Use case would be cold boot attack prevention: a trigger on rack open, scramble the keys in memory followed by shutdown in full disk encryption system. Let's assume that dirty shutdown (since we lost encryption keys) is preferable to physical access to hardware while keys are in memory.

I appreciate that threat of is theoretical if even that. Also, I know TPM or full memory encryption might be better at mitigating this threat.

So is it possible to locate where the keys are loaded to?

*EDIT* for clarity.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I worded the question poorly then. What I wanted to know if it's possible to determine where the keys I've loaded are stored.

Comment: Much more clear, however I suppose the storage location rather depends on the runtime.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I'm sure you're right. I'm hoping someone could point out if there's a way to simplify the problem. Adding a hook to kernel source would be possible (well documented, easy to read code) but it'd be less feasible to hook every crypto using program. Best solution I can think of would be a write-only device node to key's location in memory. Create a new node for every new key.

Comment: It may be easier to simply write over all of the memory in use by an application (process). If you scramble the keys then the application will become useless anyway. Overwriting kernel memory is trickier I suppose.

Comment: @MikeOunsworth That was news to me, thanks. I thought that kind of obfuscation counts as security thru obscurity and is frowned upon. I'll read up on this. Also, this also means that key management software would be the place to hook the memory locations if I want to do that. Naturally, this means FOSS only but I'll go that route anyway.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes That is definitely the path of least resistance and maybe the only way I could get this to work. It's slower than just writing a single key and writing kernel memory will panic the system and risk leaving keys in memory. I'll look at key management systems and see where that gets me.

Comment: An [HSM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_security_module) might be of use?

Comment: @NeilSmithline HSM would be a solution if very expensive one. But my endgame is to see how many different attacks I can shield against without special hardware. Think EM sidechannel or cold boots attacks, as robust a boot sequence as I can manage etc. This isn't a production environment, just a noobish hobbyist trying to learn infosec basics one small piece at a time. And keep myself busy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It *highly* depends on what software you're using to manage the keys. For example, the proprietary crypto library we use here splits the key over several memory locations, flips them big-endian / little-endian, etc and only reassembles them when they're needed. Any good crypto / key management tool will have its own bag of similar obfuscation tricks. This will make it hard for you to locate keys in memory unless you know how they've been obfuscated.

As you say in your question, TPM or full memory encryption are probably better uses of your time. Unless you know exactly which crypto libraries / key management tools are running and are willing to reverse engineer them / add key destruction hooks into their source code.

**Update**: as you say in comments, security through obfuscation is frowned upon as the only source of security (ie it doesn't protect you from highly motivated attackers), but it does still have its uses.

**Update #2**: having chatted with a colleague about this, it sounds like you're trying to make your server into an [HSM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_security_module), these are hardware devices specifically designed to manage private keys, and to wipe them if any kind of tampering is detected. If your organization is concerned about attackers having enough physical access to pull off a cold-boot attack, then you should really be using commercially-certified HSMs and not have private keys in memory at all.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I'll look into key management tools and see where that gets me. My time is cheap and I'm doing this to get better understanding of the complex world of cryptography. I'll leave the question open for a bit in case someone else wants to chime in.

Comment: Sigh, stupid minimum 6 character change quotum. "sever" should be "server" in **Update #2**.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend reading the [original paper](http://citp.princeton.edu/pub/coldboot.pdf) on the Cold Boot attack.  Section 6 explains "Identifying keys in memory."  They wrote an app called "keyfind" that you might be able to search for.

Comment: Great tip and why didn't I think of that?